# Creating A Custom HTML Module Outside the Sheet in Joomla, Not Displaying

Tags: css, joomla-template

I have a couple of Joomla! sites which I feel confident with. My Joomla! site has an artisteer template.
I recently made a "poking out" picture, that protruded the edge of the sheet, and showed an android "poking out from behind the sheet". This also has a postion:fixed attribute so that it scrolls with the user. I used a background-picture in .css to get this how I wanted it.
I would want to do the same thing for a "social box" with FB, twitter etc, using the custom HTML module, but I'm finding it difficult!

I have added the custom module to the index.php, and got the styling correct in the .css style sheet. It shows exactly where I want it on the index.php?tp=1 template preview, however, it doesnt show on the live template.
Since then, I have played around with different positions, and moved it onto the sheet and it has shown up fine, however, I would want it off the sheet to save room.
I'm starting to think that a custom module out side if the sheet isn't possible. Hopefully there are some Joomla! gurus on SO?

part of my index.php is below (i've made custom modules previous and this is how I've done it, found from Joomla! documents):

```
<?php if ($view->containsModules('right')) : ?>
<div class="art-layout-cell art-sidebar2">
<?php echo $view->position('right', 'art-block'); ?>
<div class="social">
<div id="social"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="social" /></div>
</div>
<div class="cleared"></div>
</div>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This places the module in the "right" position.

and the .css styling in the style sheet is:

```
#social {
    position: fixed;
    top: 125px;
    margin-left: 203px;
    border: solid #D5D5D5;
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
    z-index: 29000;
    width: 70px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. I have posted in the Joomla! forums and the artisteer forums, but I have had no response!

Kind Regards,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

I changed my index.php to

```
<div class="art-logo">
</div>
<div id="header_menu"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="header_menu" /></div>
<div id="social"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="social" /></div>
<?php if ($view->containsModules('user3', 'extra1', 'extra2')) : ?>
<div class="art-bar art-nav">
<div class="art-nav-outer">
```

so the

```
<div id="social"><jdoc:include type="modules" name="social" /></div>
```

has now moved, and is now the header (i think).

I then edited the div in the css to:

```
#social {
    position: fixed;
    top: 180px;
    margin: -80px;
    border: solid #D5D5D5;
    background-color: #DFDFDF;
    z-index: 29000;
    width: 70px;
}
```

and all is displaying great now!!